# Camunda correlating a message to running process instance starts new process instance

Tags: rest, bpmn, camunda

I have the following problem:

There is a message start event lets say message name is `MessageX` followed by a Task.
If i send a POST request `engine-rest/message` with the body

```
{
  "messageName" : "MessageX",
  "processInstanceId" : "null",
  "resultEnabled" : "true"
}
```

i get the answer

```
{
    "resultType": "ProcessDefinition",
    "execution": null,
    "processInstance": {
        ...
        "id": "1234-567-8910",
        ...
    }
}
```

So there is now a process with id `1234-567-8910` started and waiting on the Task. Fine.
I now want to corellate the same message to the Process Instance with the id `1234-567-8910` like so:

```
{
  "messageName" : "MessageX",
  "processInstanceId" : "1234-567-8910",
  "resultEnabled" : "true"
}
```

The BPMN looks like this:

[image]

I expect that he says something like `process 1234-567-8910 is not waiting for message` or something, but instead he starts a new process instance...

Is there a way to only corellate the message when the process is actually at some point where he is actually waiting for it?

Answer (score 1):

Messages only can be correlated when the execution token is waiting at the message event. In your case, execution token is already handed over to the task, so correlation fails and a new instance is spawned.

But why do you want to sent the same message twice? Starting an instance with a  message already delivered it. You could separate process start and message delivery by using an explicit start request (needs to separate start-event and message-event in your process-definition):

```
POST localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/<your-process-id>/start HTTP/1.1
{
    "variables": {
        "someVar": {
            "value": "hello", "type":"string"
        }
    },
    "businessKey" : "1234"
}
```

and afterwards:

```
POST localhost:8080/engine-rest/message HTTP/1.1
{
  "messageName" : "MessageX",
  "businessKey" : "1234",
  "processVariables" : {
    "someNewVar" : {"value" : 5,  "type": "Integer"}
  }
}
```

For sure you could also use p-id to correlate, but do you really want to keep track of all these id's?

KR, Joachim

Comment: I wanted to send the same message every time when a "edit" button is pressed in my frontend. In my process there are two different events (one is the start event and one is right in the Process) that are listening to that message.

Comment: That's possible for sure, but not with the shown model;) Just use the same message at two different steps within your process (and some sort of loop to get back to message wait state). BUT, the execution token still has to be waiting on the message event, otherwise you will get an error in your "client"-application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in KIE(jbpm). There the start and others nodes are signals and there is an api for those. It also accepts process variables as parameters.